# remove error message from JQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, mobile, error-handling, jquery-mobile

Is it possible to remove or ignore the error message in JQuery Mobile? I have tried using:

```
$.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
```

but as far as I can see that only has an effect on the actual loading message. Useful to know, but useless in this context.

I am using a button to submit an ajax post, and on success I am calling

```
window.location = 'insert url here'.
```

The location changes but the error appears before this occurs. By the way, the reason I am using window.location is that I am building a web app and don't want to go to safari or the android equivalent post submission.

All input is appreciated :)

Conor

Comment: What error message are you talking about?

Answer (score 2):

This is not recommended for the end user experience, but you could modify the jQM library and just comment out the error message:

(Note: this is the full version and not the min one, You would need to min it yourself)

```
//show error message
$( "<div class='ui-loader ui-overlay-shadow ui-body-e ui-corner-all'><h1>"+
    $.mobile.pageLoadErrorMessage +"</h1></div>" )
    .css({ "display": "block", "opacity": 0.96, "top": $window.scrollTop() + 100 })
        .appendTo( settings.pageContainer )
        .delay( 800 )
        .fadeOut( 400, function() {
            $( this ).remove();
     });
```

BTW IMHO I do not recommend doing this but it's an option